# SQL Coding, Unable to Limit based on where in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query I'm writing, and it's nearly perfect, excepting one error I can't seem to control for.

```
SELECT Clients.client_id,
       Clients.last_name + ', ' + Clients.first_name AS Client_Name,
       Query3.team_id,
       Query3.team_name,
       Query2.CSW_Name,
       Query1.Date_of_Service AS Last_Service_by_CSW,
       Query.Tx_Start_Date AS Tx_Start_Date,
       Query.Tx_End_Date AS Tx_End_Date
FROM Clients
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT TxPlus.client_id,
          Max(TxPlus.start_date) AS Tx_Start_Date,
                                    Max(TxPlus.end_date) AS Tx_End_Date
   FROM TxPlus
   GROUP BY TxPlus.client_id) Query ON Query.client_id = Clients.client_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT EmployeeClients.client_id,
          Employees.last_name + ', ' + Employees.first_name AS CSW_Name
   FROM EmployeeClients
   INNER JOIN Employees ON EmployeeClients.emp_id = Employees.emp_id
   WHERE EmployeeClients.case_manager = 1) Query2 ON Clients.client_id = Query2.client_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT ClientVisit.client_id,
          Max(ClientVisit.rev_timeout) AS Date_of_Service
   FROM ClientVisit
   INNER JOIN EmployeeClients ON ClientVisit.emp_id = EmployeeClients.emp_id
   GROUP BY ClientVisit.client_id,
            EmployeeClients.case_manager,
            ClientVisit.visittype_id
   HAVING EmployeeClients.case_manager = 1
   AND ClientVisit.visittype_id = 9) Query1 ON Clients.client_id = Query1.client_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT TeamClient.client_id,
          Team.team_id,
          Team.team_name
   FROM TeamClient
   INNER JOIN Team ON TeamClient.team_id = Team.team_id
   WHERE TeamClient.primary_flag = 1) Query3 ON Clients.client_id = Query3.client_id
WHERE Clients.client_status LIKE 'Active'
```

The objective is to basically pull a client record, and show the dates for their Treatment Plan, their Primary Team Assignments, their case manager, and the most Community Support service there case manager provided for them.

Right now, with the code as it's written, I get all the correct information, EXCEPT the most recent Community Support date. This returns the most recent service done by ANYONE, not the Case Manager.

I'm certain its a very simple problem, but it's driving me up the wall.

You all are an invaluable resource, and I thank you in advance.

Comment: **`Microsoft SQL Server `** or **`MySQL`**?

Comment: This is quite embarrassing, but I'm not sure. I have been shoved into administering the clinic database, so I'm learning on the fly. What would I look for that would let me know? It's an electronic record system provided by Credible Behavioral Health.

Comment: What tool you use to cooperate with database phpMyAdmin/console/SSMS? Check connection string for name :)

Comment: I use their provided query builder, as that is all they allow. It's accessed through their web portal, which is how we input and access all the data in the system.

Comment: run this query - `select @@version`.  If you get a proper response, it is most likely sql server.  if you get an error returned, it is most likely mysql.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6000.34 (X64) Aug 19 2014 12:21:34 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: It's sql server because of the + String Concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without knowing what the data looks like, I can't be 100% certain that this is the answer, but I have a pretty good feeling about it.  I believe that this is the query that is returning your, "Community Support Date".  (It wasn't identified as clearly as I would have liked, but it looks to me like this is it.)

```
(SELECT ClientVisit.client_id,
          Max(ClientVisit.rev_timeout) AS Date_of_Service
   FROM ClientVisit
   INNER JOIN EmployeeClients ON ClientVisit.emp_id = EmployeeClients.emp_id
   GROUP BY ClientVisit.client_id,
            EmployeeClients.case_manager,
            ClientVisit.visittype_id
   HAVING EmployeeClients.case_manager = 1
   AND ClientVisit.visittype_id = 9) Query1 ON Clients.client_id = Query1.client_id
```

So what you're doing is creating a subset of the data in these two tables, joined by `emp_id` and grouped by client, case manager and visit type.  Then you remove any groups that are not the case manager or visit type you want.  But by this point, you've already selected your `Max(ClientVisit.rev_timeout) AS Date_of_Service`.  I believe that if you change your `HAVING` clause into a `WHERE` clause (and thus filter before you group) you will get the results you're looking for.

EDIT:

```
(SELECT ClientVisit.client_id,
              Max(ClientVisit.rev_timeout) AS Date_of_Service
       FROM ClientVisit
       INNER JOIN EmployeeClients ON ClientVisit.emp_id = EmployeeClients.emp_id
       WHERE EmployeeClients.case_manager = 1
       AND ClientVisit.visittype_id = 9
       GROUP BY ClientVisit.client_id) Query1 ON Clients.client_id = Query1.client_id
```

Comment: I think I made the change you prescribe. I simply changed the word HAVING to WHERE, in the query (which you correctly identified as the one generating the most recent CommSupt date). However, the builder generated a generic error: Error: Invalid Custom SQL query. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Where'.

Comment: Gotcha, so I fixed it up to look like your sample. Now I'm getting this: Error: Invalid Custom SQL query. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.

Comment: Scratch that, error on my behalf. I got it in order, but still no change in the service date pulled.

Comment: I' m just guessing but you can try adding: ORDER BY Query1.Date_of_Service ASC at the end of your whole query.

Comment: My output reordered according to he last service date, but the dates themselves remain unchanged.

Comment: Maybe you could post some sample data in your question?  That might help.  As it is, we're having to make some guesses/assumptions about the data that you're querying.

Comment: Sure. What would be most useful? The whole kit is HIPAA protected, so I'd need to make some mock up data.

Comment: I'm afraid that you'll have to be the judge of that.  Ultimately we would need something that illustrates the problem.  I suspect that the `ClientVisit` and `EmployeeClients` tables would be the most likely culprits.  But that's just my suspicion based on your description.